# HttpClient through Socks 5 tunnel

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, ssh-tunnel

I have a remote server running an ssh server.
I tunnel to it by binding 9090 as a dynamic port so that local clients connected to localhost:9090 using socks5 are able to exit from the remote server. (tested with firefox and querying for "what is my ip")

Now I want my C# HttpClient to behave the same, so instead of like this:

```
HttpClient client= new HttpClient();
```

I set it up like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
           {
               Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("localhost:9090")),
               UseProxy = true
           });
// ...
client.GetStringAsync("/some/resource");
```

But that gave me an exception saying localhost scheme is not supported. So I tried:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
           {
               Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://localhost:9090")),
               UseProxy = true
           });
// ...
client.GetStringAsync("/some/resource");
```

Which results "An error occurred while sending the request."

How can I use HttpClient with an ssh tunnel ?

Comment: I am looking for the same. Did you manage to find an answer to your problem?

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja I was in a hurry, so I switched to delphi :D